# Are mirrors viable as replacement for light sources?

Tags: flash, lighting, macro, light, studio-lighting

I'm thinking about making a macro photo setup with many light sources (up to 10). It's not viable to buy 10 flashes, even cheap ones. It's more viable to buy 10 cheap lights, but it would lead to such problems as overheating, less natural colors, potentially softer photos due to vibrations (from vehicles passing by, etc).

Another alternative that I consider is using flashes + mirrors as "flash-multiplexers". I never tried it and I'd like to read some opinions about my idea.

Here is an example of usage of multiple light-sources (cheap Ikea-like lights):
[image]

Comment: Curious why ten light sources?

Comment: Curious too. How do you fit them between camera and subject? Otherwise, a lot of my at-home macro-photography is done near a wall mirror. But you can also use  [things like this](https://www.amazon.com/Etekcity-Collapsible-Multi-Disc-Photography-Reflector/dp/B00DIHSZCC/ref=sr_1_3?crid=8LEDNL1KSH34).

Comment: @BobMacaroniMcStevens, to get a lot of shadows of different sizes, angle, hardness and intensity, so that little details of the subject are more emphasized.

Comment: You should give a lot more detail about what your objective is and what you have in mind.  Mirrors cannot increase the amount of light from the flash, but they can redirect it.  You may have trouble because the longer light path means the mirrors will not be as bright so the illumination will not be as even as you want, but without details we cannot be sure.

Comment: @RossMillikan Mirrors can increase the amount of light from the flash *that lands on the subject*.

Comment: It would be interesting to see a photo of your project.

Comment: @Rafael, added an example photo.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the picture. Unless it was made with medium or large format film, it probably is not at the 1:1 reproduction ratio that “macro photography” technically means…that’s why I asked. Excellent picture by the way.

Comment: @BobMacaroniMcStevens, yes, it was made with a macro filter.

Answer (score 18):

Since you plan to take macro shots, a folded piece of paper just outside the frame might be a huge, soft light source compared to the object in the picture.

Here's an example:
[image]

And the resulting shot:
[image]

Note that putting light everywhere might result in a bland picture. You might want to experiment with black sheets of paper, in order to choose where the light doesn't land.

Before you buy any more equipment, I highly recommend you take a look at ["The Best of Dean Collins on Lighting"](https://strobist.blogspot.com/2006/08/review-best-of-dean-collins-on.html).

It's a treasure trove of information about lighting. There's an entire DVD with professional shots using only one light, and many DIY modifiers.

Comment: @GillBates thanks. You can zoom in on droplets to see what the light setup looks light. The distinct shadows might simply come from the complex geometry of flowers. I think you could get a very similar result with a "softbox" (which doesn't need to be large, only close to the flowers), one reflector and one background. One portable flash and 3 sheets of paper might be all you need.

Comment: This is probably fodder for a whole new question, but... What's the purpose of the card reflector at this location in this shot? It appears to be about 180° from the light sources, so it seems to me that the light would, more or less, just pass right by the coffee cup without really reflecting any back on to it? Curious if there was a noticeable difference without the reflector there.

Comment: @FreeMan interesting question. There definitely was a difference with and without. I'll search my catalog to see if I still have a shot without. it helped soften the shadow on the right of the cup, reduce the contrast on the cup, and bring some saturation back.

Comment: Interesting. I'm _far_ from expert, but I wouldn't have expected that. Since your whole answer centers around using reflectors, I think finding a non-reflector image would add significantly to an otherwise already good answer.

Comment: @FreeMan True. I'm on vacation, I'll look at my catalog next week. Another point is that the main flash is not pointing towards the cup. It misses it in order to feather the light, and hit the reflector more than the cup.

Comment: Fair enough! I do see now that the flash on the left does seem to be aimed more at the card - it wasn't that obvious at first. It's an excellent photo IMHO, so whatever you did worked! ;)

Comment: @FreeMan in order to check, I just looked at myself in a mirror, with a window on my back right. I brought a white sheet of paper on my left, and watched how the shadows brightened up. The difference is subtle but definitely here.

Comment: Could someone explain differences between different kinds of reflectors?

Comment: Gil - that might make a good stand-alone question. Basically it's the amount of diffusion ['spread'] & colour-cast, but it may well be worth getting someone to give it a full answer. [Thank you for the bounty, btw :)))

Answer (score 16):

Mirrors are going to make the light more of a point-source, as it's 'twice' as far away, therefore more parallel. You'd also have to be quite precise in their placement.

It would probably be cheaper, less prone to breakage & just as effective to use sheets of card, white or silver fabric reflectors or reflective "polys" [big pieces of polystyrene used as reflectors]. Each would be a diffuse light source, still further away than the initial flash, but far less directional.

Comment: Thank you for your post, good points, I'm going to bounty-reward it in any case.

Comment: If the mirror makes the flash "twice" as far away, does this also mean that the flash power diminishes by a factor 4?

Comment: Yup. Inverse square law, twice the distance, 1/4 the power [plus a bit lost to the glass itself].

Answer (score 2):

Optically, a light in a mirror is the same as a light directly shining on the subject. As Tetsujin says, they will however, have a higher effective distance. Whether this is an advantage or disadvantage depends on the situation and your taste.

Also repeating points in Tetsujin's answer, but (hopefully) expanding: the purpose of mirrors is to reflect at an exact angle, and create coherent images of the things reflected. You just want a reflection; for most purposes in photography, a coherent image of the light source is not needed and in fact a drawback. Since mirrors are more expensive than most reflectors, you're spending money preserving something (namely, light sources that are close to point-like) that you probably don't want to begin with.

Remember that *all* sources are reflectors, mirrors are just image-preserving ones. A white sheet acts like a mirror *and* a lamp shade at the same time. You do have to make sure the albedo is reasonably high, and you do have the inverse square law applied twice, but other than that, any surface can supply illumination. Also keep in mind that two surfaces that both look "white" can have slightly different spectra as far as what albedos they have at different frequencies, and your camera doesn't necessarily see color exactly the same as your eye does.

If you want more professional reflectors, you can do a web search of "photographer reflector". Basic ones will be

Comment: It looks like something got cut off at the end of the answer.